# Gallio test results showing in Output tab of Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, mbunit, gallio

Does anyone know how to have the test results of a Gallio test run (I'm using MbUnit, fwiw), show in the Output tab of Visual Studio? Right now it's opening a new window and showing the results there.

Thanks fellas,
-Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use the [TestDriven.Net](http://testdriven.net/) test runner. It's entirely compatible with [Gallio/MbUnit](http://gallio.org) and it displays the test results in the VS Output Window.

Comment: Perfect. This alleviated the issues I was having! Thanks, Yann.